# Combining lists in a predetermined format

Tags: python, list

What's the proper way to combine some lists into another, with a predetermined format?

Say I've got `a = [1, 2, 3], b = [4, 5, 6], c = [7, 8, 9]`

I want to create a list like so: `comb = [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]`.

I tried something like `comb = [(%s, %s, %s) %(a[i], b[i], c[i]) for i in range(3)]` but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your way of initializing lists is incorrect, and as far as combining lists is concerned, you may use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) as:

```
a, b, c = [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]
print zip(a, b, c)
>>> [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python proposes the keyword [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) to do want you expect.

Below is an example that works with Python 2 and Python 3

```
a = [1, 2, 3]; b = [4, 5, 6]; c = [7, 8, 9]
abc = list(zip(a,b,c))
print(abc)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have this: (%s, %s, %s)? That is something that is used for strings. For tuple assignment (as you want it), it is almost the same as assigning lists. I.E.:

```
z = (1, 2, 3)
```

If you want to use list comprehensions, like you are trying to do, you really are almost there. Just get rid of those %s things, so it's like this:

```
comb  = [(a[i], b[i], c[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
```

But if you want to do it more elegantly, stick with the zip suggestion.